# how to get the metadata "Link" parameter in S3 using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to fetch only the metadata "**Link**" parameter (entire url) in S3 using CLI or script.

[image: Amazon S3 Object]

Desired output:

```
https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Comment: There is no s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com endpoint.  For legacy reasons, the us-east-1, IPv4-only, REST endpoint is s3-external-1.amazonaws.com.  What exactly do you need to accomplish?

Comment: Also can you clarify why you are calling this the "metadata Link parameter."  Where do you see this?  It seems like non-standard terminology, since the URI/URL isn't technically metadata.

Comment: Please see attachment..if u upload the url it will show u the full link like that only

Comment: You have shown your desired output, but what is your input? Are you performing a List on a bucket, or do you know the actual Key for the file you wish to convert into a URL? (Feel free to Edit your question to provide more detail.) Also, please note that the "Link" is not a tag, nor is it metadata. It is simply a URL/URI that points to S3, names the bucket and appends the Key of the object (path + filename). You can construct it from the individual elements.

Comment: Thank you John for the detailed description. My input is I have uploaded few pics in a bucket. From the script I want to fetch the entire url of the pic which is there in s3 bucket. so end result will be to get the https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/Chrysanthemum.jpg

Comment: What is the goal here? You can't DO anything with that link, if you want someone to download you need to use a presigned link or give them access to the bucket itself.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the valid bucket object URL formats

```
http(s)://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>
http(s)://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<key>
```

So you do not need any script or CLI command as long as you know the file and the bucket.

Comment: My requirement is to get the tag only from s3 bucket...for ex.upload any pic to s3 bucket and see the "Link" tag..